# How do you write a chord that has add#9, add-9 at the same time?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, learning, self-learning

I'm confused about how to write a chord that has add#9 and add-9 at the same time. This is an example. What are the notes?
[image]

Comment: So, it has the notes F, A, C#, G# and Gb?

Comment: Do you mean write it out on a stave?

Comment: As a side note, "add-9" is not a very common form of notation, "add b9" would be preferable (if that's indeed the meaning intended).

Comment: Could you add some context? A chord with notes listed by Tim is F#min maj9. Or perhaps it's just Faug?

Answer (score 1):

You ask what the notes are. F (root), A (3rd), C♯(aug5), G♯ (♯9) and G♭ (♭9).